MicroK8s Windows Worker Node - Ingress Returns 504 Gateway Time-out
I followed a sequence of tutorials to set up a MicroK8s Cluster consisting of 1 Linux Control Plane and 1 Windows Worker Node :

https://microk8s.io/docs/getting-started
https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-portainer
https://microk8s.io/docs/add-a-windows-worker-node-to-microk8s

I deployed a sample application on the Linux Node and it worked very well, but on the Windows Node, I get a " 504 Gateway Time-out" response from nginx.
The Pod is also not reachable from its Hosting Node.
Here are the logs and resources that I think are relevant.
Nginx Ingress Controller Logs:
2024/09/23 06:56:57 [error] 26#26: *2868 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.19.30, server: diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.50.175.86:80/", host: "diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour"
2024/09/23 06:57:02 [error] 26#26: *2868 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.19.30, server: diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.50.175.86:80/", host: "diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour"
2024/09/23 06:57:07 [error] 26#26: *2868 upstream timed out (110: Operation timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.0.19.30, server: diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.50.175.86:80/", host: "diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour"
10.0.19.30 - - [23/Sep/2024:06:57:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 504 160 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:129.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/129.0" 448 15.003 [lacour-development-impact-diva-80] [] 10.50.175.86:80, 10.50.175.86:80, 10.50.175.86:80 0, 0, 0 5.001, 5.001, 5.000 504, 504, 504 d2ea2b5178aa0080a80603235b6ca38c

Ingress Resource:
$ kubectl describe ingress impact-diva -n lacour-development
Name:             impact-diva
Labels:           io.portainer.kubernetes.ingress.owner=vguillemette
Namespace:        lacour-development
Address:          127.0.0.1
Ingress Class:    public
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host                           Path  Backends
  ----                           ----  --------
  diva.impact.dev.groupe.lacour
                                 /   impact-diva:80 (10.50.175.86:80)
Annotations:                     <none>
Events:                          <none>

Service Resource:
$ kubectl describe service impact-diva -n lacour-development
Name:                     impact-diva
Namespace:                lacour-development
Labels:                   io.portainer.kubernetes.application.name=impact-diva
                          io.portainer.kubernetes.application.owner=vguillemette
                          io.portainer.kubernetes.application.stack=impact
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=impact-diva
Type:                     ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.152.183.126
IPs:                      10.152.183.126
Port:                     port-0  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
Endpoints:                10.50.175.86:80
Session Affinity:         None
Internal Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Deployment Resource:
$ kubectl describe deployment impact-diva -n lacour-development
Name:                   impact-diva
Namespace:              lacour-development
CreationTimestamp:      Fri, 20 Sep 2024 10:07:58 +0200
Labels:                 io.portainer.kubernetes.application.name=impact-diva
                        io.portainer.kubernetes.application.owner=vguillemette
                        io.portainer.kubernetes.application.stack=impact
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 2
                        io.portainer.kubernetes.application.note:
Selector:               app=impact-diva
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  100% max unavailable, 0 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=impact-diva
           io.portainer.kubernetes.application.name=impact-diva
  Containers:
   impact-diva:
    Image:      docker-registry.groupe.lacour/common/impact.diva:development
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Limits:
      cpu:     300m
      memory:  256M
    Requests:
      cpu:     300m
      memory:  256M
    Environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:                                  <set to the key 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' of config map 'global'>                                  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity:  <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url:            <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url' of config map 'global'>            Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity:  <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url:            <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url' of config map 'global'>            Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity:   <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>   Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url:             <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url' of config map 'global'>             Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity:   <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>   Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url:             <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url' of config map 'global'>             Optional: false
    Mounts:                                                    <none>
  Volumes:                                                     <none>
  Node-Selectors:                                              <none>
  Tolerations:                                                 <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  impact-diva-5c94545874 (0/0 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   impact-diva-5d5f99bfcd (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>

Pod Resource:
$ kubectl describe pod impact-diva-5d5f99bfcd-v449t -n lacour-development
Name:             impact-diva-5d5f99bfcd-v449t
Namespace:        lacour-development
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             devsiteswinb1/10.0.1.228
Start Time:       Mon, 23 Sep 2024 08:10:18 +0200
Labels:           app=impact-diva
                  io.portainer.kubernetes.application.name=impact-diva
                  pod-template-hash=5d5f99bfcd
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 5d93d376f54ca2edf6d8812857eb5d1210926a9f7283a294865b5f0893b4f98c
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.50.175.86/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.50.175.86/32
Status:           Running
IP:               10.50.175.86
IPs:
  IP:           10.50.175.86
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/impact-diva-5d5f99bfcd
Containers:
  impact-diva:
    Container ID:   containerd://906d4296acf0b3b8e52073eaedf7a7511e064e3d204f84639b6cc58a4c58cd1d
    Image:          docker-registry.groupe.lacour/common/impact.diva:development
    Image ID:       docker-registry.groupe.lacour/common/impact.diva@sha256:d2db6aba2030f965a03d0f2deadb5a8893ea68a9efb792f7a96270748603d9a8
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 23 Sep 2024 08:10:23 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     300m
      memory:  256M
    Requests:
      cpu:     300m
      memory:  256M
    Environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT:                                  <set to the key 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT' of config map 'global'>                                  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity:  <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url:            <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url' of config map 'global'>            Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity:  <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>  Optional: false
      Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url:            <set to the key 'Databases__Application__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url' of config map 'global'>            Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity:   <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>   Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url:             <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__0__Url' of config map 'global'>             Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity:   <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__SlaveAffinity' of config map 'global'>   Optional: false
      Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url:             <set to the key 'Databases__Attachment__MySqlMonSvcs__1__Url' of config map 'global'>             Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-q982v (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       True
  ContainersReady             True
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-q982v:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

In-Pod Console Check (Access Denied Expected):
C:\>curl http://localhost -v
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm="Authentification LACOUR Concept"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 07:03:02 GMT
< Content-Length: 17
< 
403 Access Denied* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

Would you be so kind to help me troubleshoot this error ?

Was finally caused by a Windows Bug: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/516.

The workaround until the Windows issue is fixed:
Add the following DWORD registry value with a value of zero. This should be added using a startup script to ensure persistence.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hns\State!FwPerfImprovementChange
Restart the Host Networking Service.
More information:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/5042881
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-10-2024-kb5042881-os-build-20348-2700-5b548143-9613-4e5a-9454-8ed9be8b2bd2
